# JSF Websocket in AWS EC2 working in localhost but not on EC2 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsf, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm using the <f:websocket> to update a chat page.

The app is running in Wildfly 20 and it's working perfectly in localhost but the websocket is giving the following error over the EC2 AWS instance.

```
jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://app.mydomain.com/javax.faces.push/incomingPush?8c34119c-cd10-41ca-bc13-65494ce18d4f' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

I also found this error in the wildfly log, that I think it has something to do (since in localhost I don't get this error):

```
2020-12-17 18:40:44,641 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (default task-9) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketChannelManager$ViewScope@6d608a43 of Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketChannelManager$ViewScope] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a week now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're getting a 404.  It's hard to determine where the issue is with the information you've given.

Comment: Please, let me know any other info you would  like to know.

If I change the domain in the url to 127.0.0.1 I get `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` instead.

I'm not sure which URL is the right one.